# Ensembles in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ensembles

I would like to use Drew McCormack's Ensembles from github to relieve my current iOS/swift/coredata/iCloud induced headache.  All of the Ensembles examples are in Objective-C.  I have it as a Framework in my project, but being a weekend coder, I can't extrapolate how to use it from the ObjC example code.

Has anyone seen a How-To for Ensembles using swift?

Adding: I have it as a framework, but how do I set it up and have it start Leeching?  The Obj-C way is to

```
//SetupEnsemble
cloudFileSystem=[[CDEICloudFileSystemalloc] initWithUbiquityContainerIdentifier:@"container"];
ensemble=[[CDEPersistentStoreEnsemblealloc]initWithEnsembleIdentifier:@"MainStore" persistentStoreURL:storeURL
        managedObjectModelURL:modelURL
cloudFileSystem:cloudFileSystem]; ensemble.delegate=self;
```

and then Leech

```
if(!ensemble.isLeeched){
[ensemble leechPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
if (error) NSLog(@"Could not leech to ensemble: %@", error); }];}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following steps describe how you add ensembles with the iCloud + Dropbox filesystem to your project:

Add a 'Podfile' to your project with this contents:

```
target :YOUR_TARGET_NAME do
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod "Ensembles", :git => 'https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles.git'
pod "Ensembles/Dropbox", :git => 'https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles.git'
link_with 'YOUR_TARGET_NAME'
end
```

Run 'pod install' from your terminal

Create a [ObjC bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Add Ensembles (and other frameworks to the bridging header):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Ensembles/Ensembles.h>
#import "DropboxSDK.h"
#import "CDEDropboxCloudFileSystem.h"
```

Happy coding:

```
var ensemble:CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble?
var ensembleFileSystem:CDECloudFileSystem?

ensembleFileSystem = CDEICloudFileSystem(
  ubiquityContainerIdentifier: "SOME_CONTAINER",
  relativePathToRootInContainer: "STORE_ROOT_PATH"
)

ensemble = CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble(
  ensembleIdentifier: "IDENTIFIER",
  persistentStoreURL: "STORE_URL",
  persistentStoreOptions:nil,
  managedObjectModelURL:"MOM_URL",
  cloudFileSystem:ensembleFileSystem,
  localDataRootDirectoryURL:"DATA_ROOT_URL"
)

e.leechPersistentStoreWithCompletion({ (error:NSError?) -> Void in
  // check for error, etc...
})
```

Comment: I'm getting build errors, probably because I'm confused about the STORE_ROOT_PATH, DATA_ROOT_URL, and maybe others.  The core data info I'm working with is `let store_url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myapp.sqlite")
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myapp", withExtension: "momd")!`

Comment: Rather then asking more and more questions here, I'll start a new question about my compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a weekend coder I would recommend using Apple's CloudKit.  It's all in swift, of course.  There are are some good tutorials at: https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/45-introduction-to-cloudkit/lessons/1

Comment: Hi John, I'm evaluating ensembles as well! I'm just curious about your comment "if you're a weekend coder, I would consider using CloudKit". My understanding is that CloudKit would require me writing all my own syncing code, whereas Ensembles would handle it for me. Am I misunderstanding the difference?